# SAS: Proc means output not as specified

Tags: sas, statistics, proc

I want to output an extended `Proc Means` for my data. The standard is `N, Min, Max, Std mean` but I need also Median.

I have a lot of variables so I do not want to specify each individually after the output out= statement like `median(var1)=var1_median` etc.

The following does not work and just gives me the standard outputs:

```
proc means data=have n mean median std; 
output out= want_means (drop=_type_ _freq_);
run;
```

this one also doesnt work:

```
proc means data=have n mean median std; 
var volume price [xyz variables];
output out= want_means (drop=_type_ _freq_);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I now use the following ,which works for me (note that I have to transpose it to have observations and not X variables...

```
proc means data=have; 
output out= want(drop=_type_ _freq_)
n= mean= median= std= /autoname ;
run;
proc transpose data=want
out=want; run;
```